# JSON Object's child array not being returned with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm having trouble getting an object's child array to be displayed with AngularJS.

In my `app.js`, I'm defining an array of objects as my main scope.

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.products = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Red Hat",
        "sku": "Hat",
        "thumb": "100x100",
        "pages": [
            {
                "id": "360",
                "imgs": "01",
                "content": "stuff"
            },
            {
                "id": "Feature",
                "imgs": "02",
                "content": "Feature stuff"
            },
            {
                "id": "Size",
                "imgs": "03",
                "content": "Data stuff"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Blue Hat",
        "sku": "Hat",
        "thumb": "100x100",
        "pages": [
            {
                "id": "360",
                "imgs": "01",
                "content": "stuff"
            },
            {
                "id": "Feature",
                "imgs": "02",
                "content": "Feature stuff"
            },
            {
                "id": "Size",
                "imgs": "03",
                "content": "Data stuff"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

When I try to display the title, sku and thumbnail, everything renders correctly. My issue is when I try to display the `pages` array. When I try to make a list of the pages and just get their id's, nothing is even rendered.

```
  <ul ng-repeat="page in product.pages">
      <li>{{pages.page.id}}</li>
        <li>{{page.content}}</li>
    </ul>
```

I'm still new to angular and I'm not certain on the correct way to do things. So where am I going wrong with my code?

I put together a **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DXyd84ZOOX8s3lIa9jNB?p=preview)** with my code. Any help or pointers in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that your `ng-repeat` for `page in product.pages` is outside of your `ng-repeat` for `product in products`.

Your html should look like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="product in products">
  <li>{{product.sku}}</li>
  <li>{{product.title}}</li>
  <li>{{product.thumb}}</li>
  <ul ng-repeat="page in product.pages">
    <li>{{page.id}}</li>
    <li>{{page.content}}</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

[Here's a working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YuGG2mPugiSYLnfaWkbz?p=preview).

Comment: No problem! Glad to have helped.